# Incomplete implementation of my class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

```
//
//  Possession.m
//  RandomPossessions
//
//  Created by Paxton Harman on 1/14/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Santa Barbara City College. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Possession.h"


@implementation Possession
@synthesize possessionName, serialNumber, valueInDollars, dateCreated;
@end

- (id)initWithPossessionName:(NSString *)name;


valueindollars:(int)value
serialNumber:(NSString *)sNumber
{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer 
        self = [super init];
    // Did the superclass's designated initializer fail?
     if (!self)
         return nil;

    // Give the instance variables initial values
    [self setPossessionsName:name];
    [self setSerialNumber:sNumber];
    [self setValueInDollars:value];
    dateCreated = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    // Return the address of the newly initialized object
    return self;

}
- (id)initWithPossessionName:(NSString *)name
{
    return [self initWithossessionName:name
                        valueInDollars:0
                         serialnNumber:@""];
}
@end

- (NSString *)description {

    NSString *descriptionString =
        [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ (%@): Worth $%d, Recorded on %@",
                        possessionName,
                        serialNumber,
                        valueInDollars,
                        dateCreated];
    return descriptionString;
}

- (id)init {
    return [self initWithPossessionName:@"Possession"
                         valueInDollars:0
                           serialNumber:@""];
}

+(id)randomPossesion {

// Create two arrays with a list of possible adjectives and nouns
// Note: When using NSArray's arrayWithObjects;, you can pass as many
// objects as you like. At the end of that list, you put nil to
// signify that there are no more objects - otherwise you will crash.
// The nil value is not added to the array, but it used by the method
// to determine the end of the list.
    NSArray *randomAdjectiveList = [NSArray array WithObjects:@"Fluffy",
@"Rusty",
                                    @"Shiny", nil];
    NSArray *randomNounList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bear",
@"Spork",
                               @"Mac", nil];

// Get the index of random adjective/noun from the lists
// Note: The % operator, called the modulo operator, gives
// you the remainder. So adjectiveIndex is a random number
// from 0 to 2 inclusive, in this case.
    int adjectiveIndex = random() % [randomAdjectiveList count];
    int nounIndex = random() % [randomNounList count];

    NSString *randomName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                            [randomAdjectiveList objectAtIndex:adjectiveIndex],
                            [randomNounList objectAtIndex:nounIndex]];

    int randomValue = random() % 100;

    NSString *randomSerialNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c%c%c",
'0' + random() % 10,
'A' + random() % 26,
'0' + random() % 10,
'A' + random() % 26,
                                    '0' + random() % 10];

// Once again, ignore the memory problems with this method
// We use "self" instead of the name of the class in class methods...
// Keep reading to find out why
Possession *newPossesion = 
    [[self alloc] initWithPossessionName:randomName
                          valueInDollars:randomValue
                            serialNumber:randomSerialNumber];
    return newPossession;
}
```

at line 14 and 19 it's giving me "incomplete implementation of possesion" and Expected '{' before 'valueindollars, respectfully. Any help?? new to cocoa

Answer (score 2):

You have two `@end` directives. Neither is in the right place. They should be at – suprise – the end of your implementation block.

In this method signature, remove the semicolon (and preferably the blank lines):

```
- (id)initWithPossessionName:(NSString *)name;

valueindollars:(int)value
serialNumber:(NSString *)sNumber
```

This error is confusing Jacob Relkin and Adam Eberbach, causing them to try to fix things that aren’t actually there.

In the convenience initializers `- (id)initWithPossessionName:(NSString *)name` and `-init`, you’re calling a method that doesn’t exist – there are several typos in the selector you’re calling in one, and some capitalization problems in the one you’d actually be defining if it weren’t for the extra semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob is right. Also you should do

```
@interface Possession (private)

- (id)initWithPossessionName:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

before your implementation block. Method declarations can't appear in an implementation; they must go in the interface. Your function prototypes are being advertised to your class only so they are in that sense private. But private isn't a special name here, you could say

```
@interface Possession (frobozz)
```

if you wanted. Just not

```
@interface Possession
```

because that would duplicate the interface definition that is probably in your .h file. 
So the whole thing must look like

```
@import "Possession.h"
// public prototypes, properties, ivars etc. in the .h file 

@interface Possession (private)
// prototypes here
@end

@implementation Possession

// all your code here

@end

// end is the last thing in the file
```

Comment: Instead of using `@interface Possession(private)`, it's more convenient to use `@interface Possession()` (anonymous category) because then you don't need a separate `@implementation Possession(private)` block but can simply put your methods into the main implementation block.

Comment: Technical term for an anonymous category (good to know if googling) is a "class continuation" :)